# Serving tar.gz file and download it on nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, fileserver

I have tar.gz file on a nodejs server. I want it to be downloadable from another nodejs app. I can do it with txt, jpeg etc... But no success with tar.gz. When I download the tar.gz file seems empty on the client.

**This is the simplified basic server that I used**

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(request, response){

fs.readFile(__dirname + "/update/test.tar.gz", (err, data) => {
     if (err) {

     } else {

         response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-gzip');
         response.end(data);
     }
});
```

**This is the client that tries to download**

```
var postData = {};

var options = {
    protocol : "http:",
    host: "localhost",
    port: 3010,
    path: '/GetFile',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(postData)
    }
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {

    var body = '';

    res.on('data', function (chunk) {

        body += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', function(){

        fs.writeFile("./test4.tar.gz", body, function(err) {

        });


    });
});

req.write(postData);
req.end();
```

It seems saving file successfully but I cant extract it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by creating stream as below.

```
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {

    var body = '';
    var file = fs.createWriteStream('./test4.tar.gz');

    res.on('data', function(chunk){
        file.write(chunk);
        }).on('end', function(){
          file.end();
        });
    });

req.write(postData);
req.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use the application/gzip content type ? I believe your issue come from there.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).